# vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined error when running Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, error-handling, undefined

am trying to run my Vue application, but I am getting the following error message:

vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined

this is how my Home.vue looks like

```
<template>
  <div>
     <p class="greeting">{{ currentHello }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "HomePage",
  data() {
    return {
      hellos: ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Hola", "Ciao", "こんにちは"],
      currentIndex: 0,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentHello() {
      return this.hellos[this.currentIndex];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    startGreetingCycle() {
      const intervalDuration = 1200 / this.hellos.length;
      let currentIndex = 0;

      const displayNextGreeting = () => {
        if (currentIndex < this.hellos.length) {
          this.currentIndex = currentIndex;
          currentIndex++;
          setTimeout(displayNextGreeting, intervalDuration);
        }

      };

      displayNextGreeting();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.startGreetingCycle();
  },
};
</script>

<style >

body {
  background: #080808;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh; /* Ensures the entire viewport is covered */
}

.greeting {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  }


</style>
```

and this is my main.vue

```
import * as Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

does anybody know how to solve this error?

I have tried restarting my computer, Vue, and clearing my browser's cache, but I am still getting the same error message.
I deletde node_modules and package-lock.json then reinstalled then build